# Data space overfllow

Tags: c, embedded, microcontroller, keil, 8051

I've done code c code in keil using different library for C8051F120. But at certain when i use my library function in main program it works good but when i uses that function in timer interrupt routine my data space gets overflow.

Can anyone please tell me what's the reason behind this and why this data space gets overflow ?

Total data space: 128 bytes

While using in main : 119 bytes

While using in timer routine: 139 bytes(overflow)

I've analyzed map file but couldn't get it. So please help me to solve this.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any of your code. Please show both versions, including the code for the called library function.

Comment: Please also show the mapfiles, at least the parts which relate to stack and interrupt stack in both cases.

Comment: It gets overflowed because your stack size is too small. When your program is somewhere deep in the stack (close to overflow), any interrupt will cause even deeper stack usage thus you may have overflow. Either do not call this function in interrupt and just set some flag or increase stack.

Comment: thank you guys for comment on my post and for sharing your knowledge with me..@tilz0R @Yunnosch

Answer (score 2):

> Can anyone please tell me what's the reason behind this and why this data space gets overflow ?

The default `small` memory model puts variables into the `data` memory space - which is only 128 bytes in total.

A possible solution could be switching the compiler to the `large` memory model, which puts variables into `xdata` memory. `XDATA` is significantly larger (8KB on the C8051F120). Note that this introduces a performance penalty - but that rarely matters on a MCU that runs up to 100MHz.

Fair bit of warning: The `C8051Fxxx` like to get stuck in the startup code due to the watchdog, in case the amount of xdata initialization is above a certain amount. The watchdog timeout is simply shorter than the time required to load xdata with values from flash. This can bite you in the `large` memory model. Workaround is using startup  code that handles the WDT correctly (or simply disables it).

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me, its really effective for me. I put my large memory model like structure into xdata and it worked..thanks